# Simple networking: Hyper-V Internal Virtual Switch on Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualization, hyper-v, windows-8.1

I am running Windows 8.1. I have downloaded Windows Vista VM for IE7 testing from http://modern.ie

I also have VirtualBox installed to use with vagrant. Since Hyper-V is [not yet supported](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1244) by vagrant.

When I create a virtual machine with VirtualBox, the default network configuration do the following:

- Webserver running on host can be accessed by guest and vice versa.
- Both host and guest OS can be accessed via the Internet.

When I create a virtual machine with Hyper-V and assign External network, the following happens:

- The host looses its Internet connectivity
- Guest gets connected to the Internet.
- Webserver running on host is not accessible on guest.

When I assign to the Internal network and in physical Ethernet connection property I share Internet connection with vEthernet Hyper-V's connection on host, the following transpires:

- Host is connected to the Internet.
- Webserver running on host is not accessible on guest.
- Guest has not Internet connectivity.

## Questions:

1. How to mimic the default behavior of VirtualBox in Hyper-V? That is; make both guest and host connected to Internet as well as internally.
2. Is it an abnormal behavior happening due to VirtualBox installation? Some kind of a conflict?

I tried Hyper-V on several other machines running Windows 8 in past. But I am never able to get the Hyper-V networking straight.

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/651860/simple-networking-hyper-v-internal-virtual-switch-on-windows-8-1). I think this will solve your issue. At least for me the hint to set a static DNS server solved my external network not resolving IP addresses.